# elasticsearch doesn't returns all hits

Tags: symfony, elasticsearch

I'm using Symfony 2.3 and ElasticSearchBundle 3.0. I implemented two fields for the search. The search works correctly but it doesn't display all results. For example: when I search for the a keyword, the number of hits are 33 hits but it returns only 10 results.
**config.php**

```
fos_elastica:
    clients:
        default: { host: localhost, port: 9200 }
    serializer:
        callback_class: FOS\ElasticaBundle\Serializer\Callback
        serializer: serializer
    indexes:
        hortis:
            finder: ~
            client: default
            settings:
                index:
                    analysis:
                        analyzer:
                            custom_search_analyzer:
                                type: custom
                                tokenizer: standard
                                filter   : [standard, lowercase, asciifolding]
                            custom_index_analyzer:
                                type: custom
                                tokenizer: standard
                                filter   : [standard, lowercase, asciifolding, custom_filter]
                        filter:
                            custom_filter:
                                type: edgeNGram
                                side: front
                                min_gram: 3
                                max_gram: 100
            types:
                business:
                    mappings:
                        name:  { search_analyzer: custom_search_analyzer, index_analyzer: custom_index_analyzer, type:string }
                        enabled: ~
                        gouvernaurat: ~
                        delegation: ~
                        postal_code: ~
#                        activities.principal:  { search_analyzer: custom_search_analyzer, index_analyzer: custom_index_analyzer, type:string }
                        activities : 
                            type : object
                            properties : 
                                principal : ~

                    persistence:
                        driver: orm
                        model: Toto\AdminBundle\Entity\EntityName
                        provider: ~
                        listener: ~
                        finder: ~
```

**controller.php**

```
public function searchEngineAction(Request $request) {
        $finder = $this->container->get('fos_elastica.index.hortis.business');
        // get data from both fields
        $querystring = strip_tags($request->get('name'));
        $querystring2 = strip_tags($request->get('location'));
        $boolQuery = new \Elastica\Query\Bool();

        // if both fields are empty then display all businesses
        if (empty($querystring) and empty($querystring2)) {
            $query = new \Elastica\Query\MatchAll();
            $boolQuery->addMust($query);
        } else {
            // create a boolean query
            if (!empty($querystring)) {

                $fieldQuery = new \Elastica\Query\QueryString();
                $fieldQuery->setFields(array('name', 'activities.principal'));
                $fieldQuery->setQuery($querystring);
                $boolQuery->addMust($fieldQuery);
            }
            if (!empty($querystring2)) {

                $fieldQuery2 = new \Elastica\Query\QueryString();
                $fieldQuery2->setFields(array(
                    'gouvernaurat', 'delegation', 'postal_code'));
                $fieldQuery2->setQuery($querystring2);
                $boolQuery->addMust($fieldQuery2);
            }
        }

        // select only enbaled business
        $enabled = new \Elastica\Query\Term();
        $enabled->setTerm('enabled', true);
        $boolQuery->addMust($enabled);
        $findAll = \Elastica\Query::create($boolQuery);
        $findAll->setSize(27);        

        // trigger search function
       $elasticaResultSet = $finder->search($findAll);
       dump($elasticaResultSet);

        // get results from 
        $findbusinesses = $elasticaResultSet->getResults();
        $noresult = '';
        if (!$findbusinesses) {
            $noresult = 'no result';
        }

        $em = $this->getDoctrine()->getManager();
        $FrontSettings = $em->getRepository('TotoAdminBundle:FrontSettings')->getFrontSettings();
        if (!$FrontSettings) {
            throw $this->createNotFoundException('Unable to find frontSettings entity');
        }

        // get all categories and activities
        $categories = $em->getRepository('TotoAdminBundle:Category')
                ->findBy(array(), array('order' => 'ASC'));

        if (!$categories) {
            throw $this->createNotFoundException('unable to find categories and activities');
        }

        $paginator = $this->get('knp_paginator');
        $businesses = $paginator->paginate(
                $findbusinesses, $this->get('request')->query->get('page', 1)/* page number */, 9/* limit per page */
        );
        return $this->render('TotoFrontBundle:Front:search_result.html.twig', array(
                    'querystring' => $querystring, 'businesses' => $businesses,
                    'FrontSettings' => $FrontSettings, 'noresult' => $noresult,
                    'categories' => $categories,
        ));
    }
```

How can I display the all the hits?

Comment: What exactly is your issue? Does it show no hits at all or just a few? Elasticsearch by default returns only the first 10 hits, but by adding the size parameter you can change how many hits are returned. Also see https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/2.0/search-request-from-size.html

Comment: @user2610529, I am sure that the issue is the default. You should post this as an answer so that it can be accepted

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Elasticsearch by default only returns the first 10 results. This setting can be modified by specifing the [from and size parameters](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/2.0/search-request-from-size.html). Note that it rarely makes sense to display all results on one page, instead use a pagination with a controllable amount of viewed items.

If you want all hits on one page also consider using the [scroll api](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/search-request-scroll.html#scroll-scan) as deep pagination can get very inefficiently when having a high amount of results.

Comment: I edited my post by adding size function and set it to 27. It returns 27 results but when go to the second page using pagination, it displays random objects not the ones I'm looking for. Check by yourself using "dentiste" keywork and type it in the first field. Website url: http://biginfo.tn/ . Please check the debug at the top of the page.

Comment: When switching to the second page I don't see the keyword anymore. When I enter it and press enter, it get's posted to the search result page, but as soon as I use the pagination only GETs to `search?page=2` are made.